# Hello, How to roll back mysql if one of queries fail to update the table

Tags: php, mysql, database, mariadb

I want to update Item quantity while database set check that quantity>0.
how to cancel all the queries if one of them not success to update (0 row affected) ?
using mysql/mariadb, php

```
UPDATE `item` 
    SET `quantity` = quantity+100 
    WHERE `item`.`itemid` = '0001';

UPDATE `item` 
    SET `quantity` = quantity-100 
    WHERE `item`.`itemid` = '0002'; --fail to update
```

Comment: have a look at [mysql transactions](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-transaction.php)

Comment: *database set check that quantity>0.* it seems it must be `quantity >= 0`...

Answer (score -1):

Join two updates into one conditional statement.

For example,

```
UPDATE `item` 
    SET `quantity` = quantity + CASE itemid 
                                WHEN '0001' THEN 100
                                WHEN '0002' THEN -100
                                END
    WHERE `item`.`itemid` IN ('0001', '0002');
```

or

```
UPDATE `item` 
    SET `quantity` = quantity + 100 * ((itemid = '0001') * 2 - 1)
    WHERE `item`.`itemid` IN ('0001', '0002');
```

or ... (many other variants)

Comment: this code not work

Comment: @mcgp The code cannot "not work". If you don't get desired result then you either receive incorrect result (what?) or receive error message (what?).

Answer (score -6):

You have to create a stored procedure.

Example here:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE  PROCEDURE `sp_name`

BEGIN

DECLARE int_count BIGINT;

START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE `item` SET `quantity` = quantity+100 WHERE `item`.`itemid` = '0001';
UPDATE `item` SET `quantity` = quantity-100 WHERE `item`.`itemid` = '0002';
    
 SELECT COUNT(itemid) INTO int_count FROM item WHERE quantity <= 0;
     
IF int_count > 0 THEN
    ROLLBACK;
 ELSE
    COMMIT;
END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Column or table CHECK constraint is already set: *database set check that quantity>0.*